# Java - Simulating a deadlock beween 3 threads and setting priorities

Tags: java, process, deadlock

I have the 3 following threads:

```
// These are the two resource objects we'll try to get locks for
final Object resource1 = "resource1";
final Object resource2 = "resource2";
final Object resource3 = "resource3";
// Here's the first thread.  It tries to lock resource1 then resource2
Thread t1 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {

    // Lock resource 1
    synchronized(resource1) {
      System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 1");

      // Pause for a bit, simulating some file I/O or something.
      // Basically, we just want to give the other thread a chance to
      // run.  Threads and deadlock are asynchronous things, but we're
      // trying to force deadlock to happen here...
      try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

      // Now wait 'till we can get a lock on resource 2
      synchronized(resource2) {
        System.out.println("Thread 1: locked resource 2");
      }
    }
  }
};

// Here's the second thread.  It tries to lock resource2 then resource1
Thread t2 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {

    // This thread locks resource 2 right away
     synchronized(resource2) {
      System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 2");

      // Then it pauses, for the same reason as the first thread does
      try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

      // Then it tries to lock resource1.  But Thread 1 locked
      // resource1, and won't release it till it gets a lock on
      // resource2.  This thread holds the lock on resource2, and won't
      // release it 'till it gets resource1. 
      synchronized(resource1) {
        System.out.println("Thread 2: locked resource 1");
      }
    }
  }
};


// t3 tries to lock resource3 then resource2
Thread t3 = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
      for(int i=1; i<=5;i++)
        System.out.println("t3 "+i);
    synchronized (resource3) {
      System.out.println("Thread 3: locked resource 3");

      try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }

      synchronized (resource2) {
        System.out.println("Thread 3: locked resource 2");
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now what I'm trying to do is simulating a deadlock, the program stops which I guess has caused a deadlock.

After the problem is, I added a for loop to print some text in each thread before the `synchronized` function. But when I set the priority for each thread, with `setPriority` I don't see the threads do their job according to their priority.

for example, I have these forloops in each thread before the first `synchronized`:

```
for(int i=1; i<=5;i++)
   System.out.println("t2 "+i);
```

and so on, t2 stands for thread 2. All I'm trying to do is making sure that priorities are working. I didn't try to run threads according to their priorities in a non deadlock program yet.

The OS or CPU might be the cause of such an issue?

Finally, my last question is can I show the priority effect in terms of resources, printing and executing time ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread priorities on most general purpose operating systems are not absolute (e.g. the highest priority thread ready to run always gets the CPU) but rather an input to a scheduling algorithm that computers a quantum - or length of time that the thread is allowed to run before relinquishing control to another one.

Therefore there is no certainty as to the sequence your threads will run, even when you do set the priorities.  All you can safely assume is that the highest priority thread is likely to get a larger share of CPU time than the lower priority one.   However, as your program is performing repeated IO (which blocks) and then sleeping, odds are that the threads get nowhere near their quantum anyway and will all be equally eligible to run when the 50ms sleep ends.

A class of operating systems - Real Time Operating Systems (RTOSs) -  do implement priority-driven pre-emptive threading behaviour (rather than time-slicing) and can yield highly predictable thread ordering.